# How to use a user-defined command in glossary file?

Tags: macros, glossaries, stackengine

I've a user-defined symbol like this:

```
\newcommand{\myexclam}{\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{}{t}{}{\rotatebox{-45}{\scalebox{.5}{$/$}}}{$!$}}}
```

This symbol should be used in one of my glossary's entries as below (`gloss.tex`):

```
\newglossaryentry{mykey}{name={\ensuremath{\delta_{\text{act}}(a,\tau)\myexclam}}, description={Activity automaton}}
```

and here is `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[doublespaced,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\myexclam}{\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{}{t}{}{\rotatebox{-45}{\scalebox{.5}{$/$}}}{$!$}}}

\makenoidxglossaries
\loadglsentries{gloss}

\begin{document}

    Here is my formula \gls{mykey}

    \printnoidxglossary[sort=standard,title={List of Symbols}]      

\end{document}
```

But the compilation throws an `undefined control sequence` corresponding to `\myexclam`.

How can I properly use this command in my glossary?

Comment: What if you paste the command's code into the glossary entry instead of `\myexclam`?

Comment: @A.Loc: The result would be the same.

Comment: @Roboticist: I get the same error using `\myexclam` directly, i.e. without `glossaries` at all, so there error is inside `\myexclam`, not with `\gls` etc.

Comment: I've written a comment to Steven B. Segletes -- it's possibily an issue with `\stackinset` from his `stackengine` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `\myexclam` must be `\protect`ed in the `\newglossaryentry`.

EDITED to add a `sort=` key to `\newglossaryentry`, since the `name` is non-alphabetic, per Nicola's instruction.  Also, loaded `hyperref` prior to `glossaries`.

```
\documentclass[doublespaced,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{gloss.tex}
\newglossaryentry{mykey}{name={\ensuremath{\delta_{\text{act}}(a,\tau)\protect\myexclam}}, 
  description={Activity automaton},sort={delta activity}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\myexclam}{\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{}{t}{}{\rotatebox{-45}{%
  \scalebox{.5}{$/$}}}{$!$}}}

\makenoidxglossaries
\loadglsentries{gloss}

\begin{document}

    Here is my formula \gls{mykey}

    \printnoidxglossary[sort=standard,title={List of Symbols}]      

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the event that there were multiple macros needing protection (for example, if `\myexclam` were used more than once), it might just be easier to define it this way, so that only a single `\protect` is required:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{gloss.tex}
\newcommand\newname{\ensuremath{\myexclam\delta_{\text{act}}(a,\tau)\myexclam}}
\newglossaryentry{mykey}{name={\protect\newname}, description={Activity automaton},
  sort={delta activity}}
\end{filecontents*}
```

Comment: The `sort` key is always needed in `\newglossaryentry` for entries that contain any (non-accent) commands when used with `\makenoidxglossaries`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Not being a glossary user, that key would be in the form of `,sort={? ? ?}`, what, exactly?  Maybe `,sort={delta actual}`?

Comment: `\printnoidxglossary` sorts according to the value of the `sort` key provided with each entry and `sort=standard` means an alphabetical sort. Since it uses TeX to sort, it only sorts according to (lowercase) character code.  If `sort` is missing it will be taken from the `name` key but the `noidx` method used here locally modifies accent commands to allow them to be stripped when the sort is obtained from the name (hence the expansion problem). I think `sort={delta actual}` sounds like a reasonable value.

Comment: This type of glossary entry would be much better with `\makeglossaries` and `makeindex`. (`name={\protect\newname}` won't work with `xindy` without the `sort` key.) By the way, didn't notice it earlier: `hyperref` needs to be loaded before `glossaries`.