# Help writing a simple long division problem with LaTex

Tags: math-mode, equations

First-time poster here and any help is incredibly appreciated. I started a new creative job and somehow got asked to write a LaTex code snippit that depicts the following division. I've tried everything I can and I'm totally stuck. It just makes zero sense to me. I understand I'm asking for your time, and I'm not sure if this is against the community rules but I'm willing to pay for the help if anyone can do this. And yes, I will be letting my boss know this isn't something to expect from me in the future. Thank you ahead of time!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Offering payment is not necessary here. Can you provide the pieces of code you have so far and post it here.

Comment: See this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395703/more-on-formatting-of-long-division) here. They are dealing your problem.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for replying. I don't have anything so far. This is a creative editorial job and I cannot overstate this enough - I don't know how to do this. I have nothing. I took a look at that link you posted and I'm not sure where I'd plug the numbers in?

Comment: There is even the [`longdivision` package on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/longdivision).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this adaption of the code from @Bernard answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395709/224762). So credits to him.

EDIT: Added the arrow

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix, arrows.meta}


\begin{document}

    \[
    \begin{array}{ rr@{} >{\color{red}}c@{}*{6}{c@{\mkern2mu}} }
        & 7 &  & . & 9 &  &  \\ \cmidrule[0.6pt](l{-0.385em}){2-8}\\[-16.9pt]
        32\;\rlap{\Large)} &252 &  & . & 8 &  &  &  \\
        & -224 &  & &\downarrow\\ \cmidrule(l{1ex}){2-5}
        & 28 &   & &8  \\
        & -28 &  &  &8  \\ \cmidrule(l{1ex}){2-5}
        & & &  & 0 &  \\
    \end{array}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]