# Tikz node or TikZmark Node, which fits for the figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikzmark

I want to draw the following picture:

[image]

But I got stuck where to start? What should I use *normal TikZ node* (`\node`) or *TikZmark Node* (`\tikzmarknode`)? I am not expert in `tikz-pgf` package. Your help is expected.

### Added:

I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\large 
\[
    \tikzmarknode{v1}{1}\tikzmarknode{v2}{4}\newline
    \tikzmarknode{A}{3}\tikzmarknode{B}{\raisebox{1em}{2}}\tikzmarknode{C}{4}\tikzmarknode{D}{5}\tikzmarknode{E}{6}\tikzmarknode{F}{3}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \tikzset{
        every node/.style={outer sep=2pt},
        lab/.style={font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt}}
        
        \draw[red] (B) to[out=90,in=90] node[lab,midway,above]{} (v2) ;  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Answering your question depends on the method you will use to create your picture in the first place (without the arrows, I mean). What did you do? Please share a compilable MWE of what you already wrote, then we could help you decide what better method to use.

Comment: @SebGlav I actually could not decided which things should I use. I need to draw it with less hustle and easy to draw. I have added my code.

Comment: Your approach is probably easiest.  A regular `\tikzmark` puts a coordinate at the baseline, from which you would have to estimate the distance and direction to start the arrow.  Here you can use the bounding box in which the letter was inserted.

Comment: One last question before trying anything: what exactly is this picture supposed to illustrate? Could you elaborate a bit? I'm not familiar with this kind of figures disposition. And is it a one shot drawing or is it supposed to be reproduced with different figures elsewhere?

Comment: This question my be related: [Help writing a simple long division problem with LaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618761/224762)

Comment: @SebGlav This is a part of division problem. But this division approach is a bit different from the conventional one. This figure actually illustrates one of the steps and will be expanded or altered for other steps. Hope you got it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\tikzmarknode` is a good idea. But first you need to draw the division problem without the arrows. An `array` works well for this. The syntax `{*{12}{c@{\,}}}` center-justifies each column but reduces the column spacing to 0, then adds a small thin space (`\,`) between each column. `*{12}` means repeat that 12 times. (You only have 7 columns at the moment, but maybe you'll add more.)

[image]

Placing the minus signs inside `\mathllap` prevents them from adding space to their columns.

Once the division problem is drawn, put the numbers that you want to be nodes inside `\tikzmarknode`. Then in a `tikzpicture` with options `remember picture, overlay`, draw the arrows from node to node using any `tikz` options you want such as `looseness=`, `in=`, `out=`, etc. You can place a node (I called it `M`) in the middle of one of those arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % needed for \mathllap
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{*{12}{c@{\,}}}
& & &1&\tikzmarknode{B}{4}& & &\\ \cline{3-8}
3&\tikzmarknode{A}{2}&\raisebox{.6pt}{\kern-.56pt)}&4&5&\tikzmarknode{C}{6}&3\\
&&&\smash{\vdots}&\\ \cline{4-8}
&&&1&3\\
&&&\mathllap{-}1&2\\ \cline{4-8}
&&&&1&\tikzmarknode{D}{6}\\
&&&&&\mathllap{-}\tikzmarknode{E}{8}\\ \cline{4-8}
&&&&&8
\end{array}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, >=latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
\draw[->](C)--(D);
\draw[<->, looseness=2.5](A.north)to[out=90, in=90]node[pos=.7](M){}(B);
\draw[->, looseness=1.5](M.center)to[out=60, in=0](E.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```